# Unable to parse CSV with empty field at the beginning in gawk

Tags: linux, awk

I created gawk(GNU Awk 5.0.1, API: 2.0 (GNU MPFR 4.0.2, GNU MP 6.1.2)) script1. here

---

input.csv:

```
,b,c,d,e,f
g,h,i,j,k,l
```

script1:

```
gawk -v FPAT='[^,"]*|"([^"]|"")*"' -v OFS=, '{print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6}' input.csv
```

script1 output:
The output of script1 is all empty!

```
,,,,,
g,h,i,j,k,l
```

---

I created script2 to make sure the field is parsed. here

script2:

```
gawk -v FPAT='[^,"]*|"([^"]|"")*"' -v OFS=, '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) printf "field #%d: %s\n", i, $(i)}' input.csv
```

script2 output:
field#1 is empty, so I confirmed that it was properly parsed.

```
field #1: 
field #2: b
field #3: c
field #4: d
field #5: e
field #6: f
field #1: g
field #2: h
field #3: i
field #4: j
field #5: k
field #6: l
```

---

Why my script1 is unable to parse CSV with empty field at the beginning in gawk?
sincerely

Comment: How is your actual Input_file looks alike? Is it always having commas as a field separator or if  not then could you please post some example which is near to your actual Input_file and we could see whats happening with it on real data then.

Comment: script1 gives the expected output for me. As an aside, to avoid the escaping hell, put your pattern between single quotes.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Thanks. I use input.csv and update script

Comment: @Casimir et Hippolyte Thanks. I use single quotes, update script

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bug, reported now to the GNU awk developers (see https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gawk/2019-10/msg00041.html) and meanwhile you can work around it this way:

```
$ gawk -v FPAT='[^,"]*|"([^"]|"")*"' -v OFS=, '{oFPAT=FPAT; FPAT=""; FPAT=oFPAT} {print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6}' input.csv
,b,c,d,e,f
g,h,i,j,k,l
```

Here's a simplified version of the problem (based on [@karakfa's earlier work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58647695/1745001)):

```
$ echo ',b' | gawk -v FPAT='[^,]*' '{print $2}'
b
$ echo ',b' | gawk -v FPAT='[^,]*' '{print $1, $2}'

$
```

It can be worked around in the same way as a previous bug (https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gawk/2017-04/msg00000.html):

```
$ echo ',b' | gawk -v FPAT='[^,]*' '{oFPAT=FPAT; FPAT=""; FPAT=oFPAT; print $1, $2}'
 b
$
```

Apparently it can also be worked around just by accessing NF, e.g.:

```
$ echo ',b' | gawk -v FPAT='[^,]*' '{NF; print $1, $2}'
 b
$
```

Comment: I appreciate your cooperation,It was very helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Not an answer, but too long for comments.

This seems a strange behavior.  A simpler test case

This works fine

```
$ echo ',b' | gawk -v FPAT='[^,"]*' -v OFS=_ '{print $1 "$"}'
$
```

This too

```
$ echo ',b' | gawk -v FPAT='[^,"]*' -v OFS=_ '{print $2 "$"}'
b$
```

But not this

```
$ echo ',b' | gawk -v FPAT='[^,"]*' -v OFS=_ '{print $1,$2 "$"}'
_$
```

Comment: Yeah, that's a bug. Change it to `echo ',b' | gawk -v FPAT='[^,"]*' -v OFS='_' '{print NF, $1, $2 "$"}'` and it outputs `2__b$` as it should.

Comment: This bug? https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gawk/2017-04/msg00000.html

Comment: @oguzismail Yup. Just checking now to see if it's identical or just related. No, it's not identical, just can be worked around in the same way. I'll email the guys anyway and post a link here when it's available.